# Towers of Hanoi Program - counter

Tags: java, counter, joptionpane, towers-of-hanoi

I am doing a Tower Of Hanoi program - there are 3 pegs and a stack of disks on peg 1 in the order of largest to smallest (largest on bottom, smallest on top). What you have to do now is move all the disks from peg 1 to peg 3, you can use peg 2 as a storage space for other disks. So far I have gotten the correct placement of disks to work (each disk is being moved correctly), now I need to create a counter variable in order, to show how many moves it took for a certain number of disks inputted by the user. For example, 3 discs would take a minimum of 7 moves.

https://www.mathsisfun.com/games/towerofhanoi.html

You can see that I have some commented out some Moves++, but wherever I place the counter it never seems to work.

```
public class TowerOfHanoi

    {//open class

    public void Answer(int numOfDisks, String Peg1, String Peg2, String Peg3, int Moves)
    {//open public void Answer

        Moves++;

        if (numOfDisks == 1)
        {//open if

            //Moves++;      
            System.out.println("\nNumber of Moves so far: " + Moves + "\nMove disk on Peg " + Peg1 + " to Peg " + Peg3);

        }//close if

        else
        {//open else

            //Moves++;
            Answer(numOfDisks - 1, Peg1, Peg3, Peg2, Moves);
            System.out.println("\nNumber of Moves so far: " + Moves + "\nMove disk on Peg " + Peg1 + " to Peg " + Peg3);
            //Moves++;
            Answer(numOfDisks - 1, Peg2, Peg1, Peg3, Moves);

         }//close else

    }//close public void Answer

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {//open main

        TowerOfHanoi TOH = new TowerOfHanoi();  
        String numOfDisks = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a number!");
        int NumberOfDisks = Integer.parseInt(numOfDisks);
        System.out.println("\nNumber of disks chosen: " + NumberOfDisks);
        int Moves = 0;
        TOH.Answer(NumberOfDisks, "1", "2", "3", Moves);

    }//close main

}//close TowerOfHanoi class
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: it did not really help much, just got to know where to put the counter vairable

Comment: With 3 disks [D1,D2,D2], with D1 being topmost at the start, D1 moves every second time, D2 every 4th time and D3 every 8th time... plusminus 1. You need 2^3-1 moves for 3 disks. Why count if you can compute? For N disks you need 2^N-1 moves.

Comment: Please show us examples of both the expected and actual output.

Comment: I run your program and it has 7 output as expeted if you choose 3 as number.  So the number of moves so far should be 7 in final.?

Comment: correct Goldbones, the counter is not making any sense it would go from like 3,2,3,0,1

Comment: i will try computing thats a really good idea @ user2225104

Comment: @Nick, there is a closed form solution to this problem. See chapter one of Concrete Mathematics by Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 0):

Increase Moves every time you make a move i.e. in front of each of the two println statements since those represent one move being made.
Next you need to return Moves from your Answers method. Place `return Moves` at the end of the method. And when you call the method do `Moves = Answer(numOfDisks - 1, Peg1, Peg3, Peg2, Moves);`

Comment: He's already counting every move by incrementing after every call.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you are facing is that you are using recursion and pushing the move counter into the new call of `Answer` without returning anything. When returning the move counter will restore its previous value.

This could be solved by returning the value, or a better solution from my point of view by introducing a member variable. Remove it from the parameter list, and use a public member. Then you could add TOH.moves at the end of your code.

You will then get consistent counts, and can play around with the placement, but it seems correct without looking to closely on your code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move the bottom most (n'th) disk from p1 to p3, you first need to move the n-1'th disk from p1 to p2 (and cleanup). Then you move p1 to  p3 and then you move the rest from p2 to p3.

From this textual description, it is obvious, that you only really make a move in the "move p1 to p3" section. This is where you should increase your move counter.

In order to show this in a compact form, here a very short version of towers of hanoi (consider this a rapid prototype for your java program ;) It also shows how to use the return value of the function to obtain - here the move list - in your case, your counter.

```
let rec hanoi n p1 p2 p3 acc =
    match n with
    | 0 -> acc
    | _ -> 
        hanoi (n-1) p1 p3 p2 acc
        @ [p1,p3]                   // this is where a move is added
        @ hanoi (n-1) p2 p1 p3 acc 

hanoi 3 1 2 3 [] |> List.length
```

To make it a bit easier to see, here the version which only counts:

```
let rec hanoi1 n p1 p2 p3 acc =
    match n with
    | 0 -> acc
    | _ -> 
        hanoi1 (n-1) p1 p3 p2 acc
        + 1                   // this is where a move is added
        + hanoi1 (n-1) p2 p1 p3 acc 

hanoi1 3 1 2 3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:
You could try an iterative program, so it's easier to handle the counter. You can [take a look here](https://thewalnut.io/visualizer/visualize/1322/342/), there's a visualization of Towers Of Hanoi based on [this iterative program](https://thewalnut.io/simulations/edit_agent/109/) that's demonstrated that solves the problem in the minimum number of steps.

I know it is not in JAVA, but you'll see that porting the program is not too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Non Iterative tower of Hanoi solution

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TowerOfHanoi {

    private static int SIZE = 5;

    private class stack {

        stack(int size) {
            dataElements = new int[size];
        }
        int[] dataElements;

        int top = -1;

        private void push(int element) {
            dataElements[++top] = element;
        }

        private int pop() {
            if(top==-1) {
                return -1;
            }
            int topEle = dataElements[top];
            dataElements[top]=0;
            top --;
            return topEle;
        }

        private int top() {
            if(top==-1) {
                return -1;
            }
            return dataElements[top];
        }

        private boolean isEmpty() {
            return top == -1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        towerOfHanoi(SIZE);
    }

    private static void towerOfHanoi(int number) {
        initialize(number);
        if(number % 2 == 0) {
            solveEven(number);
        } else {
            solveOdd(number);
        }
    }

    private static int recentMoved = -1;

    private static stack source = new TowerOfHanoi().new stack(SIZE);
    private static stack intermediate = new TowerOfHanoi().new stack(SIZE);
    private static stack destination = new TowerOfHanoi().new stack(SIZE);

    private static void solveEven(int number) {

        while(destination.top < number-1) {
            if(!movePlates(source, intermediate, destination)) {
                if(!movePlates(intermediate,destination,source)) {
                    if(!movePlates(destination, source, intermediate)){
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }



    private static boolean movePlates(stack from , stack dest1 ,stack dest2) {
        boolean movedPlate = false;
        if(from.top()== recentMoved) {
            return movedPlate;
        }
        if((!from.isEmpty()) && from.top()<(dest1.top()==-1?10000:dest1.top())) {
            dest1.push(from.pop());
            recentMoved=dest1.top();
            movedPlate = true;
        }
        else if((!from.isEmpty()) && from.top()<(dest2.top()==-1?10000:dest2.top())){
            dest2.push(from.pop());
            recentMoved=dest2.top();
            movedPlate = true;
        }
        if(movedPlate)
            display();
        return movedPlate;
    }

    private static void display() {
        Arrays.stream(source.dataElements).forEach(System.out::print);
        //.stream().fl.forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.print("\t");
        Arrays.stream(intermediate.dataElements).forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.print("\t");
        Arrays.stream(destination.dataElements).forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.print("\n");
    }


    private static void initialize(int number) {
        for(int i=number;i>0;i--) {
            source.push(i);
        }
    }

    private static void solveOdd(int number) {
        while(destination.top < number-1) {
            if(!movePlates(source, destination, intermediate)) {
                if(!movePlates(destination,intermediate,source)) {
                    if(!movePlates(intermediate, source, destination)){
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```